# Hi, I am working on Protractor-Cucumber. How to parse JSON test data in protractor?

Tags: protractor

my test data - car_data.json

```
[
  {
    "car_name": "some_car",
    "chasis_number": "some_num"
  },
  {
    "car_name": "some_car",
    "chasis_number": "some_num"
  }
]
```

**protractor.config.js:**

```
params : require('./data/test-data.json')
```

and I am accessing test data using "browser.params.car"

Question: I have a functionality where a user can add car into table and a chasis_number of car will be added into table. I want to filter the table by entering chasis_number on table column. For this I want to first validate with the car_name from test data car_data.json and enter respective chasis_number in filter field. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `filter()` method on `car_data.json` file and find the chasis_number based on given car_name,

```
  function getChasisNumberFromTestData(car_name) { 
       var filteredArray = browser.params.car.filter(function(carObject){
            return carObject.car_name == car_name;
       });

      return  filteredArray.length ? filteredArray[0].chasis_number : "Car name not found in testdata";
    }
```